# Lambda abstraction pattern matching in haskell

Tags: haskell

I am trying to write a function which outputs all variable names. When used on the example below, the output should be

```
*Main> used example
     ["a","b","x","y"]
```

This is what I have written so far...

```
import Data.Char
import Data.List

type Var = String

data Term =
    Variable Var
  | Lambda   Var  Term
  | Apply    Term Term
--  deriving Show

instance Show Term where
  show = pretty

example :: Term
example = Lambda "a" (Lambda "x" (Apply (Apply (Lambda "y" (Variable "a")) (Variable "x")) (Variable "b")))


pretty :: Term -> String
pretty = f 0
    where
      f i (Variable x) = x
      f i (Lambda x m) = if i /= 0 then "(" ++ s ++ ")" else s where s = "\\" ++ x ++ ". " ++ f 0 m 
      f i (Apply  n m) = if i == 2 then "(" ++ s ++ ")" else s where s = f 1 n ++ " " ++ f 2 m

used :: Term -> [Var]
used (Variable n) = [n]
used (Lambda n t) = "\\" ++ n ++ ". " ++ used t
used (Apply t1 t2) = used t1 ++ used t2
```

The problem lies in the line `used (Lambda n t) = "\\" ++ n ++ ". " ++ used t`, I get this error message:

```
list.hs:28:47: error:
    lexical error in string/character literal at character '\n'
   |
28 | used (Lambda n t) = "\" ++ n ++ ". " ++ used t
```

Why am I getting this complaint?

Comment: `"\\"` is the single-character literal you want. `\"` is how you specify a literal double-quote inside a string literal.

Comment: The lexer recognizes the string `"\" ++ n ++"`, the token `.`, and the *start* of a string `" ++ used t` before it reaches a newline in the middle of the string literal.

Comment: The error message doesn't match your actual code, though. Did you save the file before trying to parse it again?

Comment: @chepner I have just run the code again with `used (Lambda n t) = "\\" ++ n ++ ". " ++ used t` and i get the following error `list.hs:28:42: error:
    • Couldn't match type ‘[Char]’ with ‘Char’
      Expected type: [Char]
        Actual type: [Var]
    • In the second argument of ‘(++)’, namely ‘used t’
      In the second argument of ‘(++)’, namely ‘". " ++ used t’
      In the second argument of ‘(++)’, namely ‘n ++ ". " ++ used t’
   |
28 | used (Lambda n t) = "\\" ++ n ++ ". " ++ used t`. How should `++ used t` be wriiten so that all variable names are captured?

Comment: `++` is expecting a `String` for both its arguments. It's not immediately obvious to me what list you want to return if `used t` returns a list or 2 or more values.

Comment: cheers @chepner I tried this `used (Lambda n t) = "\\" ++ n ++  .  used $ t`, but it came up with `list.hs:28:35: error: parse error on input ‘.’
   |
28 | used (Lambda n t) = "\\" ++ n ++  .  used $ t`, how could this line be written?

Comment: I'm pretty sure you need either `used (Lambda n t) = n : used t` to return the list of all the variables (bound and free), or `used (Lambda n t) = filter (/=n) (used t)` to return the list of the free variables, only. This allows duplicates in the returned list -- that might be OK or not, depending on your requirements.

Answer (score 0):

You are copying and pasting from examples too much.  Keep thinking about what the function is supposed to mean as you are writing it.

```
used (Variable n) = [n]
```

This is correct: the set of variables used in a term which is just a variable is the variable used.  For example, the set of variables used in the term `x` is just `[x]`.

```
used (Apply t1 t2) = used t1 ++ used t2
```

This is also correct<sup>1</sup>: the set of variables used in say `(x y z) (w x y)` is the *union* of the variables used in `x y z` and in `w x y`: that is `[x,y,z,w,x,y]`.

So now let's consider the case you are struggling with.

```
used (Lambda n t) = ...
```

The code you have seems to be attempting to print the the term into a string, which is not what we are trying to do here -- we are trying to find the set of used variables.

Let's consider an example: we have a term like `(\x. x y z)`, and we want to find out what its used variables are. Before trying to come up with the general solution, ask yourself what the result should be in this example.

If this function is going to be nicely recursive, can we express your expected result in terms of the used variables of `x y z`?   How do we transform the set of used variables of `x y z` into the set of used variables of `\x. x y z`?

---

<sup>1</sup> Though you might get duplicates.